# Selection sort on an array of char in Java

Tags: java, char

Trying to selection sort a string by converting string to an array of char everything seems right to me, but it doesn't sort the array completely and returns a half sorted array.

```java
public class Anagram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "ksdvbjksbjdjkk";
        int minInd,
        min,
        currChar;
        char temp;
        char str1arr[] = str1.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < str1arr.length; i++) {
            minInd = i;
            min = str1.charAt(i);
            for (int j = i; j < str1arr.length; j++) {
                currChar = str1.charAt(j);
                if (currChar < min) {
                    minInd = j;
                }
            }
            temp = str1arr[minInd];
            str1arr[minInd] = str1arr[i];
            str1arr[i] = temp;
        }
        for (char e: str1arr) System.out.print(e);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
jkbsbdkvdjjkks
```

Comment: I suggest stepping through your program with a debugger, or adding some printlns. You'll soon see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try out this code.**

```
public class SELSORT{
static void selectionSort(char a[],int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        int min_index = i;
        char t1 = a[i];
        String mst= String.valueOf(t1);
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            String t=String.valueOf(a[j]);
            if(t.compareTo(mst) < 0)
            {
                mst = String.valueOf(a[j]);
                min_index = j;
            }
        }

        if(min_index != i)
        {
            char temp = a[min_index];
            a[min_index] = a[i];
            a[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    String test="asdqwdfnshvbsudgfuyqsadbcsabcuwnbcsnm";
    char a[] = test.toCharArray();
    int n = a.length;
    System.out.println("Given array is");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    selectionSort(a, n);
    System.out.println("Sorted array is");

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in the logic of your algorithms. Here how it should be:

1. Iterate from arr[1] to arr[n] over the array.
2. Compare the current element (key) to its predecessor.
3. If the key element is smaller than its predecessor, compare it to
   the elements before. Move the greater elements one position up to
   make space for the swapped element.

You getting first two steps right, but for third step (nested loop) you should go in opposite direction, and swap elements with your key, if element is greater than key.

You can refer to this article, it has better explanation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/
The logic of an algorithm was taken from this article.

Comment: i did the third step too, as you can see in the code using the temp var i pushed the smallest value in the unsorted part of the array to the left

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "ksdvbjksbjdjkk";
        int minInd,
        min,
        currChar;
        char temp;
        char str1arr[] = str1.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < str1arr.length; i++) {
            minInd = i;
            min = str1arr[i];    // 1 mistake
            for (int j = i; j < str1arr.length; j++) {
                currChar = str1arr[j];    // 1 mistake
                if (currChar < min) {
                    minInd = j;
                    min = currChar;    // 2 mistake
                }
            }
            temp = str1arr[minInd];
            str1arr[minInd] = str1arr[i];
            str1arr[i] = temp;
        }

        for (char e : str1arr)
            System.out.print(e);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

1. `str1` always unchange；but `str1arr` changed every round of for loop;
2. `min` need to update the smallest character from `i` to `j`.